# why does DNN9 installation wizard return with an error

Tags: installation, dotnetnuke, wizard

I have been trying to install DNN9.9.0
After the installation wizard opens and I fill out the form, an error is returned stating "Server Error in "/" Application. Object reference not set to an instance of an object", with the following stack trace:

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
DotNetNuke.HttpModules.OutputCaching.OutputCacheModule.OnResolveRequestCache(Object sender, EventArgs e) +678
System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +222
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +219
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +93

what could the issue be? and how can i resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

It is not obvious.

You might want to try doing the installation on a test server using nvQuickSite (nvquicksite.com) and compare how that installation in done relative to yours.

In the meantime, make sure that you UNBLOCKED the zip file before copying its contents to your website folder.  Also, verify file permissions - the IIS Worker Task needs to have full permissions for the website directory.